# Separating the file for static class method/member

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class `CommonFunc` which store global params.
for example

in `main.dart`

```
class CommonFunc{
     static bool _isLoad = false;
}

void main(){
    CommonFunc._isLoad = true;
}
```

It works but then now,

I want to use `CommonFunc` from multiple dart file,
So I try to separate the file

in `commonfunc.dart`

```
class CommonFunc(){
     static bool _isLoad = false;
}
```

in `main.dart`

```
import 'commonfunc.dart';

void main(){
    CommonFunc._isLoad = true;
}
```

im `main2.dart`

```
import 'commonfunc.dart';

void getAlteredFlg(){
    print(CommonFunc._isLoad);
}
```

However in this case returns `Error: Getter not found:`

How can I separate the file for static method/member??

---

I change _isLoad -> isLoad

It works.

Comment: print(CommonFunc.isok); what is `isok`?
I don't see definition for `isok`

Comment: That's my mistake. I corrected.

Comment: I checked and in my flutter project everything is worked.
Could you please create minimal reproducible flutter project on github and share link?

Comment: You write `class CommonFunc() { ... }`. There shouldn't be a `()` there. Other than that, the code looks correct and should work. Are `main.dart` and `main2.dart` both in the same directory as `commonfunc.dart`?

Comment: That's my silly fault. I use `_isLoad` for my real code. I changed `_isLoad` -> `isLoad`. it worked. So much thank you for your help and attention. My way of question was not good.

Answer (score -1):

simply make on class with name "constant" and put constant variable in it and use that variable throughout project.

only write like below :

```
const String appName = "Flutter App";

const bool isLoad = false;
```

Comment: fonderful answer from person who claimed 1 year experience in Flutter